# Cannot implicitly convert type string to int C#

Tags: c#

```
// read the data from the file and store it in the ArrayList
        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('=');
            JaiAlai jaiAlai = new JaiAlai();
            jaiAlai.JaiAlaiNumber = columns[0]; // throws an error here
            jaiAlai.BetTotal = columns[1]; // throws an error here
            jaiAlaiNumbersList.Add(jaiAlai);
        }
```

Comment: Provide an explication to your question. Question with mostly code are not allowed

Comment: You should google the error it's telling you exactly what the problem is look up how to use `Convert.To` method or what `Casting` is

Comment: also just out of curiosity what type of data is in the file and what is the delimiter? why don't you read all of the data at one time split based on that delim.. can you show one line of the data that's in the text file you are using.. I think there is a better way to writing logic and or creating your own data parser working with Class Objects and mimicking the class structure to be the same as the file layout and then creating a List<ClassObject> to store the data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and) it gives 3 methods to convert strings to Ints.

In brief they are here:

```
jaiAlai.JaiAlaiNumber = Int32.Parse(columns[0]);
Int32.TryParse(columns[0], out jaiAlai.JaiAlaiNumber);
jaiAlai.JaiAlaiNumber = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]);
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that the 2nd example will not work if `JaiAlaiNumber` is a property and not a field.

Answer (score 4):

A String cannot be implicitly converterd to an int in c#. you need to call the conversion explicitly:

```
jaiAlai.JaiAlaiNumber = Int32.Parse(columns[0]);
```